# VS2015 - Ending instrumentation profiling executable after a certain duration to match load testing test mix

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I wish to know if it is possible (via configuration setting or property setting of the performance session possibly) to have my project be executed during a profile ([instrumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264993.aspx), not sampling) run but to have it exit after a period of time so that it may collect its analysis results.

My project is a self hosted service and such will not exit on its own. As of now I have to manually click "Stop profiling" for it to end the profiling run and collect its results.

I have a separate [load test](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release) project that will execute its test run for a configurable amount of time. It will automatically when the test is complete start its data collection and analysis.

Is it possible to (without me manually having my application forcibly end after a period of time I set and doing it that way) have my instrumentation profiling match my load test analysis end/run time?

Comment: I believe [vsperfcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182403.aspx) is the what you use to start and stop profiling from the command line. If there's a way to run code and the beginning and end of the load test it would be something like `Process.Start("vsperfcmd", "/start:TRACE /output:loadtest.vsp")` to start and `Process.Start("vsperfcmd", "/shutdown")` to stop profiling.

Comment: Great idea thanks.